# VB.net Getting the InnerText of href using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: vb.net, href, html-agility-pack, innertext

I have now updated my code (Thanks Tim for helping me learn) which is already working but it doesn't give me the right links i want.

Here is my working code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim WebSource As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.google.com.ph/search?hl=en&as_q=test&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=countryCA&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=ctr%3AcountryCA&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&cr=countryCA&fp=1&hl=en&lr=&q=test&start=20&tbs=ctr:countryCA")

    Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
        doc.LoadHtml(WebSource)
        Dim links = GetLinks(doc, "test")
        For Each Link In links
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Link.ToString())
        Next
    End Sub


   Public Class Link
        Public Sub New(Uri As Uri, Text As String)
            Me.Uri = Uri
            Me.Text = Text
        End Sub
        Public Property Text As String
        Public Property Uri As Uri

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format(If(Uri Is Nothing, "", Uri.ToString()))
        End Function
    End Class


    Public Function GetLinks(doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument, linkContains As String) As List(Of Link)
        Dim uri As Uri = Nothing
        Dim linksOnPage = From link In doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                          Where link.Name = "a" _
                          AndAlso link.Attributes("href") IsNot Nothing _
                          Let text = link.InnerText.Trim()
                          Let url = link.Attributes("href").Value
                          Where url.IndexOf(linkContains, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 _
                          AndAlso uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, uri)

        Dim Uris As New List(Of Link)()
        For Each link In linksOnPage
            Uris.Add(New Link(New Uri(link.url, UriKind.Absolute), link.text))
        Next

        Return Uris
    End Function
```

### I am currently new to this HtmlAgilityPack, I am still learning please bear with me.

My Main Goal:

Sample link: `http://www.google.com.ph/search?hl=en&as_q=test&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=countryCA&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=ctr%3AcountryCA&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&cr=countryCA&fp=1&hl=en&lr=&q=test&start=20&tbs=ctr:countryCA`

My expected link outputs which contains the word "test":

```
www.copetest.com/‎
www.testofhumanity.com/
www3.algonquincollege.com/testcentre/‎
www.lpitest.ca/‎
testtube.nfb.ca/‎
www.ieltscanada.ca/testdates.jsp‎
https://www.awinfosys.com/eassessment/fsa_fieldtest.htm‎
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use the attribute `href` instead, also note that .NET is case-sensitive by default

```
For Each link As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
   Dim href = link.Attributes("href").Value
   If href.IndexOf("test", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
       ListBox1.Items.Add(href)
       ' or
       ListBox1.Items.Add(link.InnerText)
   End If
Next
```

Here is a method that should return all links in  a document as `List(Of Link)`. `Link` is a custom class with two perties, one for the text and the other for the `Uri`:

```
Public Class Link
    Public Sub New(Uri As Uri, Text As String)
        Me.Uri = Uri
        Me.Text = Text
    End Sub
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Property Uri As Uri

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} [{1}]", Text, If(Uri Is Nothing, "", Uri.ToString()))
    End Function
End Class

Public Function GetLinks(doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument) As List(Of Link)
    Dim uri As Uri = Nothing
    Dim linksOnPage = From link In doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                      Where link.Name = "a" _
                      AndAlso link.Attributes("href") IsNot Nothing _
                      Let text = link.InnerText.Trim()
                      Let url = link.Attributes("href").Value
                      Where uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, uri)

    Dim Uris As New List(Of Link)()
    For Each link In linksOnPage
        Uris.Add(New Link(New Uri(link.url, UriKind.Absolute), link.text))
    Next

    Return Uris
End Function
```

Here is the requested overload that checks if an url contains a given text:

```
Public Function GetLinks(doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument, linkContains As String) As List(Of Link)
    Dim uri As Uri = Nothing
    Dim linksOnPage = From link In doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                      Where link.Name = "a" _
                      AndAlso link.Attributes("href") IsNot Nothing _
                      Let text = link.InnerText.Trim()
                      Let url = link.Attributes("href").Value
                      Where url.IndexOf(linkContains, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 _
                      AndAlso uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, uri)

    Dim Uris As New List(Of Link)()
    For Each link In linksOnPage
        Uris.Add(New Link(New Uri(link.url, UriKind.Absolute), link.text))
    Next

    Return Uris
End Function
```

**Edited** now tested, works, use it in the following way:

```
Dim site = File.ReadAllText("C:\Temp\website_test.htm")
Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(site)
Dim links = GetLinks(doc)
For Each Link In links
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Link.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: what will i call to display the links? i tried link.InnerText but still no result

Comment: @MarcIntes: Why not `href` or `link.InnerText`? Edited my answer.

Comment: The program is now displaying links but it has included uneeded ones that starts with /search?, /url?. I only want to display links starting with http:// and still has the word "test" on it. Is that possible?

Comment: I have tried link.InnerText again but it does not display the link. instead it displays words like, Images, Maps, Play, Youtube, Translate, Books

Comment: @MarcIntes: Try my added method to detect all links, i haven't test it yet, though.

Comment: Here is the generated URL output i have extracted to a textfile. They look messy, not really a URL format. Not the expected output i wanted tho but i want to perfect this program. I will attach it in a textfile. http://www.mediafire.com/download/8hpv6e5hcu8e87c/linkOUTPUT.txt

Comment: try testing it with this google search link i am using
http://www.google.com.ph/search?hl=en&as_q=test&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=countryCA&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=ctr%3AcountryCA&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&cr=countryCA&fp=1e63a873f2e9c884&hl=en&lr=&q=test&start=20&tbs=ctr:countryCA

Comment: I have tested it with the google link you have posted and the code extracterd 44 valid URL's + Text (note that i've overridden ToString).

Comment: I have just tested your code and yes it works. but i want to have the feature of displaying only links that has the word "test". is it possible? where should the condition be placed. i am really sorry, i am new to this HtmlAgilityPack but i want to learn.

Comment: @MarcIntes: Do you want to search for a given string in the text or in the link or in both, does it need to be a whole word or a substring? However, i've showed already a way above, just add the `href.IndexOf("test", ...` to the `LINQ` query as `Where` or add it to the loop the follows in an `If`.

Comment: the specified word should be in the link and not in the word. For example if i specify it to test. The links generated should contain the word test. www.drivetest.ca/
www.drivetest.ca/EN/bookatest/Pages/Road-Test-Booking.aspx
www.drivetest.ca/EN/drivereducation/Pages/Driver-Testing.aspx
www.cic.gc.ca/english/citizenship/cit-test.asp

Comment: where exactly should i place the condition? I am quite confused.

Comment: @MarcIntes: I have edited my answer to include an overload that filter links by a given text(case-insensitively). Search for "requested overload that checks if an url contains a given text".

Comment: I have tried the code and made the word "test" as basis. Now it does not display any links. I am still basing with the google search URL that i have.

Comment: @MarcIntes: So have you used  it in this way: `Dim links = GetLinks(doc, "test")`? I have tested it with your goggle-search link and it returned 27 links where the url contained "test".

Comment: It works now but in my case it only returned 9 links and all links has the word google in it. This was my output: http://www.mediafire.com/download/8hpv6e5hcu8e87c/linkOUTPUT.txt

my main target is to generate links that are not related to google.

Comment: @MarcIntes: I have stored the google-site as text-file and used `File.ReadAllText` and `HtmlDocument.LoadHtml(text)` to load all the html. Then i got 27 links with 27 different text properties and 27 different url's where every url contains the substring "text"(case doesn't matter). However, i assume that the question is answered, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is answered however the results are only related to google. My main purpose is to get the links from the google search results. I really need this project to be finished. it lacks something but i don't know how.

Comment: Please check my post. i have edited the bottom part with a sample link and what i want to be extracted from that link.